Help dsolve obtain this solution to standard second order ode with missing x and y
Could someone find a smart way to help DSolve solve this second order standard ode? This is second order nonlinear ode with missing $x$ and missing $y$.
ode = y''[x] == Sqrt[1 + y'[x]^2]
ic = y[0] == 1

V 14.1 can't solve it. It says
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]


I have not had chance to check earlier versions of Mathematica. This is using V 14.1 on windows 10.
May be someone has tricks to help DSolve. I solved this by hand and Mathematica says my solution is correct.
Here is the solution I obtained and Mathematica verification
 mysol = y -> Function[{x}, Cosh[x + C[1]] + 1 - Cosh[C[1]]]
 Assuming[Element[{x,C[1]},Reals],Simplify[ode/.mysol]]
 (* True*)

And
 Assuming[Element[{x, C[1]}, Reals], Simplify[ic /. mysol]]
 (* True *)

Hand solution
\begin{align}
y^{\prime\prime} &  =\sqrt{1+\left(  y^{\prime}\right)  ^{2}}\tag{1}\\
y\left(  0\right)   &  =1\nonumber
\end{align}
Let $p=y^{\prime}$ then
$y^{\prime\prime}=p^{\prime}$. Hence the ode becomes
\begin{equation}
p^{\prime}=\sqrt{1+p^{2}}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Solving this as first order gives
$$
p\left(  x\right)  =\sinh\left(  x+c_{1}\right)
$$
But $p=y^{\prime}$ hence the above becomes
$$
y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =\sinh\left(  x+c_{1}\right)
$$
Integrating gives
\begin{align}
y  & =\int\sinh\left(  x+c_{1}\right)  dx+c_{2}\nonumber\\
& =\cosh\left(  x+c_{1}\right)  +c_{2}\tag{3}
\end{align}
Now we need to apply IC's to find $c_{1},c_{2}.$ We only have one IC $y\left(0\right)  =1$. Applying this to the above solution gives
\begin{align*}
1  & =\cosh\left(  c_{1}\right)  +c_{2}\\
c_{2}  & =1-\cosh\left(  c_{1}\right)
\end{align*}
Hence (3) becomes
$$
y\left(  x\right)  =\cosh\left(  x+c_{1}\right)  +1-\cosh\left( c_{1}\right)
$$

"14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" can't solve it, either.

$Version
"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"
Try
DSolve[{y''[x] == Sqrt[1 + y'[x]^2], y[0] == 1}, y, x]
(*{y -> Function[{x}, 1 - Cosh[C[1]] + Cosh[x] Cosh[C[1]] + Sinh[x] Sinh[C[1]]]}*)

